# Rewrite trouble with “fake” folder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have made a  fake directories to show specific content using this line

> RewriteRule ^service/online/$ service.php [L]

The issue is it works fine if the URL is like this

> www.site.com/service/online/

But if the URL is like this

> www.site.com/service/online

it wont work

is there any command to make it work in both scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteRule ^service/online/?$ service.php [L]
```